# Calculating field based on content from another table with no join in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, modelbuilder, arcgis-10.3, python-parser

I'm trying to work out how if (at all) it is possible to do a field calculation where there is no join or relationship between two attribute tables in ArcGIS 10.3.1. I've searched all over the place for a solution.

In my example, my model already selects some features based on an attribute, resulting in a featureclass with approximately 2000 features, with population figures assigned to them. I already have a table with the significant loadings that each of the population figures has towards a final score.

I basically want to be able to do the following calculation.

```
[Featureclass Field Value]*[Table Field Significant loading]
```

I'm trying to avoid "hard coding" the significant loadings into the field calculation so that I can just update the table, rather than having to change several parts of the model, when/where necessary.

I can't join or relate the tables within ArcMap as they have no common field.

I suspect that this might be able to be done with Python but it's been a while since I used it and I'm getting errors every time I try so I think I may be missing something fundamental, not seeing the wood for the trees.

My first attempt is this but IDLE gives me an errors after I define the parameters (ie: when I tell it I want it to multiply stuff)

```
import arcpy
import os

# Defined within model
SLO65Sing = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) #Significant Loading field 1
SLO65All = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) #Significant Loading field 2
ValO65Sing = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) #Value field 1 
ValO65All = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) #Value field 2 
FSO65Sing = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) #Factor Score field 1
FSO65All = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) #Factor Score field 2

def Calc_O65Sing(SLO65Sing*ValO65Sing)

Calc_O65Sing(!FSO65Sing!)

def Calc_O65All(SLO65All*ValO65All)

Calc_O65All(!FSO65All!)
```

Note: moved this over from Stackoverflow when I realised I had posted it in the wrong place!

Comment: Just off the top, each def line should end with a colon, the line(s) inside the defs need to be indented, and exclamation points are field calculator syntax not Python. Eventually, I think you'll want to read your values into a dictionary using an arcpy.da.SearchCursor and write the calculation output using an arcpy.da.UpdateCursor, but that's a pretty change from what you've got here.

Comment: Ok, just to make sure I have understood you correctly, I've got some missing indents and colons, I can't use field calculator syntax in my script and I should be looking to using SearchCursor and UpdateCursor to do the calculations?

Comment: The problem I see is that you are trying to do calculations on strings.  GetParameterAsText returns a text string, not a number.  So youre expecting numbers from your first and last 2 parameters, but are getting text strings.  If you're returning field names, you'll need to get the values out of the fields for the calcs.  The code as written is multiplying two field names, and !FS065Sing! is trying to call a field but you have not specified what layer it's from.  Look at code samples for the field calculator.  You'll probably need to start over with new logic.

Comment: You can use field calc logic, but you haven't even called the field calc management in your script

Comment: @jbalk Thanks for the pointers, I had a sneaky suspicion that GetParameterAsText wasn't quite being used appropriately but don't/didn't know enough arcpy/python to work out what it *should* be.  Ultimately I want to be able to incorporate the script into a much larger model (hence the attempt to get parameters), modelbuilder can do every other task I want it to, just not this one.

I've been working my way through ESRI's examples with field calculator but must have got the wrong end of the stick.

Comment: here are some examples for the field calc with code samples:  http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/calculate-field-examples.htm. Start there. Figure out the calculations you need to make and how you need to format the expressions in the code. Here's the syntax of the tool in arcpy:  arcpy.CalculateField_management(in_table, field, expression, {expression_type}, {code_block}). If you don't know about variables in Python you need to research that. You can set each parameter as a variable to make it easier to insert the parameter.  e.g. inTable = r"C:\Temp\Default.gdb\TEMP"

Comment: feel free to ask specific questions about whatever aspects of the field calc code that you don't understand.  Also check out stack overflow for python questions.

Answer (score 1):

I do believe I pulled together what now seems like quite a simple solution. I've used da.SearchCursor and da.UpdateCursor and been able to use GetParameterAsText. As my significant loadings for my factor scores are only in one row of my table I was able to tell arcpy to just look at that row. The code is below:

```
#Factor score calculation for population values and significant loading
#Date: January 2017
#Purpose: to be incorporated into ArcGIS models so that the user can calculate factor scores for energy sustainability.
#Further information: will only work if significant loading table has one line


import arcpy
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) #Define working environment (geodatabase)
fc = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1) #Feature class with population values
tbl = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3) #Table with significant loadings
valfield = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2) #Field in fc that has population values
slfield = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4) #Field in tbl with relevant significant loading value
factfield = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(5) #Field which will be populated with factor score

slcursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(tbl,slfield)
for row in slcursor:
    sigload = row[0]

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc,[valfield, factfield]) as ucursor:
    for row in ucursor:
        row[1]=row[0]*sigload
        ucursor.updateRow(row)
        print (row)

del row
del ucursor
```

It seems to work fine (I've checked the maths), I just need to incorporate it into my model now - I've written it here in such a way that I should be able to re-use this script across other parts of the model where I need to calculate other significant loadings as well.

Comment: Note that if you want to use this script several times within a model then it is worth removing the requirement for the workspace to be set as things can get a bit messy! I also ensured that it had a derived Output featureclass in the parameters so that it could be linked into the next tool.